# How to set the Portrait and landscape orientation in android manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Portrait mode is working and landscape is not showing.

android:screenOrientation="portrait" // Here i need to show both portrait and landscape.

Comment: This line: android:screenOrientation="portrait" tells the app to always stay in portrait mode. Just remove it from your manifest to allow both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```

This is the default value and the system chooses the orientation.

alternatively, you can use:

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

In this case, device orientation sensor determinates the screen orientation.

Try one and the other to see which one works best for you.

EDIT:
For a specific class, you can do this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YOUR_CLASS"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"  // or what you want
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: I have 10 modules, one module only  I need to show portrait and landscape both.

Comment: You can use differents formats for different classes. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I know this option.But My class extends from fragment not an activity.